How to loop through function and value of different class in c++
So I am trying to basically do a* on a task planner, coz action typically have cost(risk, time, resources spent etc) and reward(effects) so I want to put it as an a* problem but for that I made each action as a class, each with an ID and a function to calculate the effect, my understanding is since everything is different, I have to make them into different classes, inherit the same base to ensure they all have the same content but just each is different.
The problem right now is that how I defined the classes, the ActionID is declared in the subclass, not in the base class, and when I do
vector<ActionBase> action_set = {a_forward,a_curve_l};

for (auto action : action_set) 
    {  
        Serial.print("%d", action->ActionID);
    }
    Serial.print("\n");

it cannot print the action ID, the error message say:

'class ActionBase' has no member named 'ActionID'; did you mean 'ActionBase'?

in the header action.h
class ActionBase{
  public:
    
    double Hcost;        //Heuristic of action
    double Gcost;        //negative constrain/cost of action
    double eX,eY,eTheta; //effect of the action
    int spd_l=0;
    int spd_r=0;
};

class moveForward : public ActionBase{
  const int ActionID = 1;     //ID of the action
  void get_effect(double cX,double cY,double cTheta){
    eX = cX + unit_dist*cos(cTheta);
    eY = cY + unit_dist*sin(cTheta);
    eTheta = cTheta;
  }

  void exe_action(){
    digitalWrite(LD_PIN,0);
    digitalWrite(RD_PIN,0);
    analogWrite(LS_PIN, walk_spd);
    analogWrite(RS_PIN, walk_spd);
    spd_l = walk_spd;
    spd_r = walk_spd;
  }
}a_forward;

class moveCurve_l : public ActionBase{
  const int ActionID = 2;     //ID of the action
  void get_effect(double cX,double cY,double cTheta){
    
  }

  void exe_action(){
    digitalWrite(LD_PIN,0);
    digitalWrite(RD_PIN,0);
    analogWrite(LS_PIN, walk_spd);
    analogWrite(RS_PIN, run_spd);
    spd_l = walk_spd;
    spd_r = run_spd;
  }
}a_curve_l;


vector<ActionBase> action_set = {a_forward,a_curve_l};

in the main code:
void loop() {

    Serial.print("Action ID");
    for (auto action : action_set) // access by reference to avoid copying
    {  
        Serial.print("%d", action.ActionID);
    }
    Serial.print("\n");
  

}

in my understanding, it shouldve printed Action ID1 2, but as of now it is error message:

'class ActionBase' has no member named 'ActionID'; did you mean 'ActionBase'?


"my understanding is since everything is different, I have to make them into different classes" no, that's absolutely not the case. You can use polymorphism and inheritance for this, but it doesn't seem very advantageous to do that here.

Create a vector of base class objects and store derived class objects within and What is object slicing and polymorphism without pointers

There are (at least) 2 issues in your code:

ActionBase does not contain a member ActionID (only the derived classes contained it).
This is the reason for the error you get when attempting to access action.ActionID, where action is of type ActionBase (since it is an element in vector<ActionBase> action_set).
⇒ The easy solution is to add ActionID to ActionBase (and remove it from all the derived classes).

vector<ActionBase> action_set is storing elements of type ActionBase by value.
This means then when you attempt to store objects of derived classes (like I imagine a_forward and a_curve_l are), they are sliced. This is not what you want.
⇒ To solve change action_set to be a vector of pointers to ActionBase.
Better still use smart pointers that will manage the lifetime of the objects for you, e.g: std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ActionBase>>.
Pointers allow the usage of plymorphism in C++.


Finally, these issues suggest that you can benefit from learning C++ from a good book.
See: The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List.
